# QML change screen width in runtime

Tags: qt, qml

I try to create application based on current width/height screen size. I have several monitors: 2k and 4k. Then I start application on 2k, it is initially determined width with 4k monitor, but it isn't that.

Window size based on screen size:

```
Window {
  width: 0.42 * Screen.width
  height: 0.85 * Screen.height
  x: Screen.virtualX + 0.5 * Screen.width - 0.5 * width
  y: Screen.virtualY + 0.5 * Screen.height - 0.5 * height

  onWidthChanged: console.log("window width: ", width)
}
```

After startup i received following log:

```
qml: window width:  1612
qml: window width:  806
```

And broken animation:

[image: Startup window width is broken]

Comment: what are these magic numbers and what do you want to get using it? what exactly broken with your animation?

Comment: @folibis what magic numbers are you talking about? in code its just a coefficient. in log its its a log after strartup

Comment: animation on 4k monitor: [normal animation](https://i.imgur.com/lCBvpg0.gif).  
  
animation on 2k monitor: [broken animation](https://i.imgur.com/3MbXVTC.gif)

Comment: I would suggest using `Qt.application.screens[i].width` ( i index of the screen you're interested in) based on the number of screens attached instead of `Screen.width`; see if that helps

Comment: you can also force your application to open in screen 1 or 2 using `screen: Qt.application.screens[0] or 1 ` inside your window

Comment: And what is your question? (Usually indicated by _**?**_)

Comment: @derM how to fix it? and why is it perform that?

Comment: Can you make that code example more complete? I don't know what those animations are. And I don't understand your problem with the Window size. If I interpret those animations right, the Window size is pretty stable.

Comment: @derM full qml file [there](https://github.com/fasterbru/interactive-chooser/blob/100f13988b5688baa5acfbb93e34a95e645b5ded/main.qml). The problem is that when the animation starts, it captures the size of the window, which is incorrect on startup. I made the code above, which show that window size is really incorrect on startup. I think we can get around this with deferred animation start, but i dont understand how to startup animation after window is size initialized. And i want to know why am i have that behavior